# How can I write in nth column of a file in awk?

Tags: shell, awk

For example:

```
abc
xyz
123
546
```

input.txt:

```
asdad
asdad
adghf
dfytr
```

I wanted to add the above column in 2nd column. The expected output is given below.

output.txt:

```
asdad  abc
asdad  xyz
adghf  123
dfytr  567
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste` is the easiest solution. Here's an awk example that doesn't have to store the entire first file in memory:

```
awk '{getline second < "example"; printf("%s\t%s\n",$0,second)}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is `paste` rather than `awk`. You could *do* it in `awk` but you'll probably find that `paste` is easier:

```
pax> cat qq1
asdad
asdad
adghf
dfytr

pax> cat qq2
abc
xyz
123
546

pax> paste qq1 qq2
asdad   abc
asdad   xyz
adghf   123
dfytr   546
```

Use `paste -d' ' qq1 qq2` if you want a space rather than a tab for the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `bash`

```
exec 4<file2
while read -r line1
do
 read -r line2 <&4
 echo $line $line2
 done < file1
exec 4>&-
```

Comment: This should work in other sh-like shells, too, not just bash. You should precede the reads with `IFS= `, though. Also, you should check your edge cases: if the last line of file1 doesn't end with `\n`, I think the while-block here won't be executed for it.

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {x[NR] = $0} NR != FNR {print x[FNR], $0}' col1_file col2_file
```

Though its probably better to use paste