# How can I write in 2nd column keeping the previous column is empty of a file in shell/awk?

Tags: shell, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I write in nth column of a file in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396990/how-can-i-write-in-nth-column-of-a-file-in-awk)

For example:

```
abc
xyz
123
546
```

input.txt:

```
asdad
asdad
adghf
dfytr
```

output.txt:

```
asdad
asdad
adghf
dfytr
       abc
       xyz
       123
       546
```

Comment: where does 'abc xyz 123 546' come from?

Comment: Please turn the title into a valid English sentence - I don't understand the question.

Comment: @whg : thats the text i want to add in the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange strange request. How about you tell us what you want, we are not going to steal your ideas, or maybe we will..

But presuming example text is in a text file how about

```
(cat input.txt; cat example.txt | awk '{ print "      "$0}') > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example I would do:

```
cat input.txt | awk '{ print $0" abc xyz 123 546" }' > output.txt
```

Comment: Hi, Please check the required format.Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: suyogss, looks like SO formatting got the better of you. do you even need awk? where does the first example text comes from?